# Paypal smart buttons actions.order.capture()

Tags: javascript, paypal

How to get data out of object details? I can't find it on the paypal documentation! 
Just gets undefined.

```
     // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details + '!');
                });
            }
```

Comment: console.log(details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the documentation in this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/) in the response section. For example to get the payer name you can write:

```
details.payer.name.given_name
```

or the order id like this:

```
details.id
```